# How to get a TextPosition Object instance using PDFBox 2.0.2

Tags: java, pdfbox

Ok, maybe there is something that I don't understand about using PDFBox, anyways, in several examples that I've seen around, everyone keeps mentioning about using TextPosition to determine the size of a font, or if said font is bold and stuff like that.

I've seen that the TextPosition class has many useful methods for font information, but I can't find anywhere how to obtain a TextPosition by using say, a TextStripper or anything, so, how do you do it?

I want to do this because I'm working with a PDF from a client and I have to read an account number from the PDF Document, then mask it like this "###-******" and then rewrite it in the same position, but I also want to use the correct font and the correct size and weight.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `PDFTextStripper` works by means of a basic engine that processes content streams. This basic engine calls call back objects registered for the content instruction in question. Text drawing content instruction call back objects (via some helpers) generate `TextPosition` instances for their text which is then forwarded to the `PDFTextStripper` method `processTextPosition` which collects them after some processing. Eventually, when you request the string value from the stripper, `writeString` is called for the collected, sorted `TextPosition` objects.

Comment: @mkl so...if I want to know the exact information about a piece of text, like font type, size, weight and the like, I have to extend PDFTextStripper?

Comment: Thus, if you want to work with `TextPosition` objects, derive a class from `PdfTextStripper` (or alternatively its parent class) and override one of those two methods, `processTextPosition` or `writeString`.

Comment: @mkl ok..thanks a lot

Comment: Please have a look at the PrintTextLocations.java example from the source code download. And update to PDFBox 2.0.6.